# What is the correct domain for a new translation in a PrestaShop class override?

Tags: module, overriding, prestashop, translation

Can you help me with the use of the "domain" parameter in `$this->trans()` function ?

In my own module I have an override for the CartRule class. My override works correctly - it is copied from my module to the override folder by Presta and the code functions.

I have a new translated string inside, and I do not know what value to give for "domain".

My code:

```
$this->trans('Promotion codes cannot be combined', array(), 'Shop.Notifications.Error'); \\ ID, parameters, domain
```

For domain I have tried:

1. "Shop.Notifications.Error" (same as the other strings): and then looked in BO > Theme Translations > My Theme (or classic theme) > French (store language)
2. "Modules.[Mymodule].Admin" (for Mymodule I used a captialized short name): and then looked in BO > Module Translations > My Module > French (store language). This approach follows the [PrestaShop rules](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/creation/module-translation/new-system/#translation-domain).

Each time I have not found my string.

Do you have some ideas?

N.B. other answers on SO make use of `$this->l` which is not available in this context.
I have also tried `$this->module->trans()` but "module" is not available in this context.

Comment: Sorry forgot to say this is PrestaShop v1.7.6.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all in your module we have to specify which strings are translatable.

**Translating for Prestashop (version 1.7.5 and older):**

TPL:

```
    {l s='My text to translate' mod='modulename'}
```

PHP:

```
    $this->module->l('My text to translate');
```

**Translating for Prestashop (version 1.7.6 and newer):**

TPL:

```
    {l s='My text to translate' d='Modules.Modulename.Somefile'}
```

TWIG:

```
    {{ 'My text to translate'|trans({}, 'Modules.Modulename.Admin') }}
```

PHP:

```
    // For back-office translations we use "Admin"
    $this->trans('My text to translate', array(), 'Modules.Modulename.Admin');

    // For front-office translations we use "Shop"
    $this->trans('My text to translate', array(), 'Modules.Modulename.Shop');
```

Ash you can see we need to declare its a translatable string from a **Module**, with the **Modulename** (with a capital), and then define where the translatable string is located **Admin, shop**

**Important note**
Using the prestashop new translation system needs to be declared in your module. so in your main php file, mymodule.php add following code:

```
    public function isUsingNewTranslationSystem()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

**PrestaShop Developer Documentation (translations)**

Information about the Classic module translation system (1.7.5 and <) can be [found here](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/creation/module-translation/classic-system/).

Information about the New module translation system (1.7.6 and >) can be [found here](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/creation/module-translation/new-system/).

**Translating your module:**

After defining all translatable strings we install our module to a Prestashop web-shop.

**When our module is installed we have to go to:**

1. Back office
2. International -> Translations
3. Modify translations
4. Type of translation -> *Installed modules translations*
5. Select your module -> *modulename*
6. Select your language -> *Language you want to translate*

This progress will generate a translation file (.php) in your module.

*Translation file location: modulename/translations/isocode.php*

Good to know is that when you have one translated PHP file of your module (*example en.php*) you can translate the same, en.php, file multiple times and save it under a different isocode for example nl.php.

Comment: Thanks. You have repeated most of what I have said in my question. I believe the relevant part of your answer is to use the `isUsingNewTranslationSystem` function, which I shall try.

Comment: Its just a way to give a full answer which could help other people in the future since the translation method only changed recently. The `isUsingNewTranslationSystem` is the mistake you made in your codding. You also did not point out which version you where using that is why i needed to point out the new translation is only available for the newest prestashop versions.

Comment: I solved my problem! Just to highlight what I had to use: 1) `$this->trans('My text to translate', array(), 'Modules.Modulename.Admin')` and 2) `isUsingNewTranslationSystem`. In PrestaShop v1.7.6.5. Thanks @Crezzur