# Problem of custom module translation prestashop 1.7.8.1

Tags: module, prestashop-1.7

I have built my own module and in the BO when I search my module and trying to translate it I am redirected to

> "shopadmin/index.php/improve/international/translations/?lang=fr&type=modules&locale=fr-FR&selected=Module_Name&_token=OeEwKt4lWTUTcBerD-_w7LXvoA1Dyl3lcu3cBrYtkaA"
> instead of
>
> "shopadmin/index.php?controller=AdminTranslations&type=modules&module=ag_jsccustom&lang=fr&token=a74aaad65ca627b7ca6bfdc37235594f"

Anyone can help me with this weird issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct domain for a new translation in a PrestaShop class override?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64115300/what-is-the-correct-domain-for-a-new-translation-in-a-prestashop-class-override)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. You have to add this function to your module’s main class:

```
public function isUsingNewTranslationSystem()
{
    return false;
}
```